# Grub command line when computer starts

Tags: grub2

I dont know if you remember me but you answered my question earlier today in ubuntu help, but i didnt get it. When my computer turns on it loads into a screen looking like this. It's just a grub command line and i have no idea what to do. All my schoolwork is in it. What do I do?